# Location of persistent files in bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I have created a bootable USB of ubuntu using startup-disk-creator and added the persistence of  around 2GB on the USB..I booted through the USB. I downloaded some documents made some changes and saved the documents.

Now when I try to boot from that usb I am getting some kind of boot error. I can format the USB and make it bootable once again that is not an issue but I need those documents.

Where are they stored? how can I retrieve those without booting from that USB?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post should help you, I've used it myself to access the persistence file. http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/02/06/howto-mount-usb-persistent-casper-rw-file-in-linux/

Here are the commands:

MOUNT

```
mkdir ~/caspermnt
sudo mount -o loop /media/USB/casper-rw /home/alex/caspermnt/
```

To unmount

```
sudo umount ~/caspermnt/
```

Just change the /media/USB/ for the mounted location of your mounted USB stick which contains the casper-rw file you want to view the contents of and the /home/alex/caspermnt/ for the mount point on your system.